# Building a distributed Vue CLI project when the build binary is included in gitignore?

Tags: vue.js, build, gitignore, vue-cli

New to Vue, and using @vue/cli 4.4.6.

I used Vue CLI to create my project, and noticed that under `node_modules/.bin` directory (that Vue CLI created), there is -- amongst many other binaries -- one called `vue-cli-service` that *appears* to be the Vue CLI build tool.

This is a bit strange to me, coming from a predominantly "backend" background using external build tools like Gradle, Maven and SBT, to have the build tool embedded inside a project! I would have expected a scenario where you download `vue-cli-service` as a command-line tool (just like I did with `vue-cli`) and then direct it at the project you want to build. But this would be like each and every Java project containing a copy of Gradle or Maven itself inside of it! Is this really the intention of a properly-formed Vue project or did I mess something up somehow?

I ask because `vue create hello-world` creates a `.gitignore` that specifically lists `node_modules` in it...

...so aren't these mutually exclusive conventions?

1. `vue create hello-world` creates a "raw" (unbuilt) project that contains `node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service` which appears to be the way to build it. but it also mentions `node_modules` in the `.gitignore`
2. so Developer #1 creates a new project and is able to build it, and they push it to a git repo. Since `node_modules` is listed in the `.gitignore`, the build tool is not included in the push
3. Developer #2 pulls the repo down to work on a new feature branch. But whoops. Since `node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service` was ignored, they don't have it in their local branch, and so they can't build it.

I *know* I must be missing something here, I just don't know what it is. Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's common in Node projects for build utilities to be [specified as `devDependencies`](https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file) in the project's `package.json`, and this is acceptable because the utilities themselves are usually relatively small in size and quick to install. Only Node and a package manager (`npm` or `yarn`) should be preinstalled on a developer machine.

Developers are expected to install these `package.json` dependencies to bootstrap development (using `npm install` or `npm ci` if a `package-lock.json` exists), similar to how prerequisite Gradle/Maven build plugins need to be installed post-clone for the project to build successfully. Each dependency's version string specified in the `package.json` (which is always commited to source control) ensures that all developers and CI are using the same version of the dependency.